# When is the additive identity not the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My teacher cryptically mentioned today that the zero vector is not always the additive identity. When asked for clarification I was told "we'll get there".

He did confirm it is always **0** in matrices filled with real numbers, but I can't think of or find any matrix, whether complex or variable or whatever where anything else would work, or where the zero vector wouldn't work.

It might be half a joke to keep me interested, but I'll be a minkeys uncle if it didn't work!

I don't know, any ideas?

Comment: As @Batman explains, the zero vector of a vector space always is the additive identity of this vector space. I suspect your professor could have meant that the zero vector of a vector space could be distinct from the additive identity of some other addition on the same set, or that the addition of the vector space is an "addition" in name only (@mrf gives such an example).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, there was some weird question yesterday about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics which give some unusual outcomes. Maybe this is more of the same, as usual I can't read minds.

Comment: thanks guys I can't wait to see what my Professor comes up with, I feel like I should pick an "acepted answer" now , but can't figure out how (if I could I'd pick darij grinberg's comment but will probably go with batmans)

Comment: On any uncountable set $X$ and for any element $x \in X$, one can define a vector space structure on $X$ such that $x$ is the additive identity (the 'zero vector'). This is achieved by a [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) which can also be used to construct the example in mrf's answer (use the map $\ln : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$). I talk about this concept in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/618859/39599) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402931/39599).

Answer (score 7):

That depends on what you mean by the zero vector.

If you want, you can consider $\mathbb{R}_+$ (the set of positive real numbers) as a vector space, where you define $x\oplus y = xy$ and $\lambda x = x^\lambda$. Then the "additive identity" is actually $1$ (but should probably be called the zero vector in this strange context).

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but are you saying were in R1, and if so wouldn't landau=x. Ill have to hit this with fresh eyes in the morning, I must be missing something (possibly a lot)

Comment: No, the underlying set is not $\mathbb{R^1}$, just the **positive** real numbers, and the above formulas *define* vector addition and scalar multiplication on this set.

Comment: isnt the positive numbers by definition not a vector space because scalar multiplication of negative one makes addition not hold? Can we really just redefine addition and multiplication this way? thank you for your quick reponse, I feel I should take some time to grasp what your saying before responding further.

Comment: The positive reals are not a vector space **under the usual operations**, but you can check that with the above definitions, it is.

Comment: yeah it's an easy check but it seems like changing the definition of addition changes the definition of a vector space, idk I think I get it but forgive me if it seems a little trivial. My mind went racing with this question and I was kind of hoping there was a different kind of answer. Does redefining the most basic of operations ever yield a useful result in your experience? btw I love the creative answer, your right you can do anything you want but doesn't it compromise the structure needed for useful mathematics

Answer (score 2):

A vector space forms a group under addition:

1) If $a,b$ are vectors, $a+b$ is a vector.

2) $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$ for vectors $a,b,c$.

3) $a+0 = 0+a = a$ by *definition* of the zero vector $0$ (i.e. the zero vector is *defined* to be an additive identity as in the [vector space axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html)).

4) $a+(-a) = (-a) + a = 0$ , i.e. additive inverses exist.

In a group, one can easily show an additive identity is [unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity#The_additive_identity_is_unique_in_a_group) (hence why we say "the" additive identity).

Thus, the zero vector is the only additive identity.

Comment: Thats what I figured but the other answer makes me and my teacher are hurting my brain tonight! But your answer makes sense, its defined that way for a reason. much more pondering is called for. Also sorry for half stealing your name, if I wouldn't've picked it (but I would still be the real Batman) if Id've known

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is not to confuse the **abstract** notion of a vector space with **concrete** vector spaces. What do I mean  by this?

#### The notion of an *abstract* vector space

Well, if $0_\mathbb{V} \in \mathbb{V}$ is a distinguished element of a non-empty set $\mathbb{V}$, $\mathbb{K}$ a field, and $\oplus : \mathbb{V} \times \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ and $\otimes : \mathbb{K} \times \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ two operation such that $0_\mathbb{V}$, $\oplus$, and $\otimes$ satify the vector space axioms; then we can call the algebraic structure
$$
(\mathbb{V}, \oplus, \odot, 0_\mathbb{V})
$$
an **abstract** $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. It is **abstract** in the sense that $\mathbb{V}$, $\mathbb{K}$, $\oplus$, $\odot$, and $0_\mathbb{V}$ are placeholders for **concrete** mathematical objects. Nonetheless, we want to be able to talk to others about the different placeholders, which is why we agree upon calling the symbol $\oplus$ *vector addition*, the symbol $\odot$ *scalar multiplication*, and the symbol $0_\mathbb{V}$ *additive identity*.

**Supplement**:
To show how important it is to keep the different notations apart, consider the *linear combination*
$$
v = k_1 \odot v_1 \oplus k_2 \odot v_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus k_n \odot v_n = \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{n} k_i \odot v_i.
$$
Then we call the symbol $\bigoplus$ *vector summation*.

#### A *concrete* vector space 1

A standard example of a **concrete** $\mathbb{R}$-vector space is $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot, 0)$. In this example, *vector addition*, *scalar multiplication*, and *additive identity* actually coincide with usual *addition*, usual *multiplication*, and the number *zero*, respectively. A linear combination of vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n \in \mathbb{R}$ is
$$
v = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} k_i \cdot v_i,
$$
i.e., the *vector summation* coincides with the usual *sum*.

#### A *concrete* vector space 2

Another example was given by @mrf: If you consider the **concrete** $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $(\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \cdot, \hat{},1)$, where the symbol $\hat{}$ shall denote usual exponentiation, then *vector addition*, *scalar multiplication*, and *additive identity* correspond to usual *multiplication*, usual *exponentiation*, and the number *one*, respectively. A linear combination of vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is
$$
v = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} (v_i)^{k_i},
$$
i.e., the *vector summation* coincides with the usual *product*.

Comment: ...wow...I seemed to have asked a very experienced question for sitting in elementary linear algebra, thank you for taking the time I will understand your post (wheather it takes me a few years or not i've copy pasted it into my questions folder. Thank you for taking the time